# Delete sheet if exists in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DeleteSheets2()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name = "HIT_Qualys_Scan" Then
        Sheets("HIT_Qualys_Scan").Delete
    End If
    
    If WS.Name = "Status" Then
        Sheets("Status").Delete
    End If
    
Next WS

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The above works but I always end up getting an Error that I have to End and then run the Sub again.

I get:

[image: run-time error 424]

with line:

> If WS.Name = "Status" Then

Once I hit "End" and run it again, it works. Is there a way to avoid this error? I am confused why it runs the 2nd time once I hit End.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that if `WS` is on sheet `HIT_Qualys_Scan` then you delete it with that first `If` statement. `WS` at that point is nothing because its object is deleted.

So when you do `If WS.Name = "Status" Then` it freaks out. There is no `WS.Name` anymore. It can't determine the property `Name` of an object that doesn't exist.

Instead test for both sheet names and delete by referring to `WS`:

```
Sub DeleteSheets2()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name = "HIT_Qualys_Scan" OR WS.Name = "Status" Then
        WS.Delete
    End If     
    
Next WS

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't getting WS.Name again before checking for the other sheet, so it had nothing to reference.

Comment: You get similar, although different, oddities when you iterate over rows and selectively delete. You will delete the row you are on, which will cause the variable you are iterating to set to the next row before that iteration ends. Then it loops/iterates to the next row, effectively skipping the row between. You have to be careful with deleting inside loops.